# Application wide price formatting

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am working with an existing bespoke ecommerce platform which until recently had no requirement to manipulate the price which is stored with a product in the database (other than multiply by quantity etc). I've now been tasked with building the functionality which will allow these prices to be viewed with or without VAT, with customisable currency based on a site wide setting or per user with regard to both exchange rate and currency symbol. The theory behind the settings/per user/locale etc is not the problem, it's the best way to change all of the pricing across the whole site.

A bit of background

- Output is buffered so I have access to the entire output before it's sent to the browser in `$output`
- There's no existing abstraction on the pricing.
- There are places in the templates which have the price without the symbol  in the format 0.00 (for JavaScript based calculations) as well as ones with the symbol in the format £0.00
- Things like adding/removing from the basket are completed with Ajax and the new price returned in JSON format
- Some pricing variables are buried in large multidimensional arrays which are constructed in the core/application classes. Some of which are used for further calculations both within the core/application classes in the templates.

Options I've considered

- Suffer the performance hit and `preg_replace_callback('/&pound;(?:<.*>|\s*)?(\d*\.\d\d)/i'...);` on `$output`. This however doesn't resolve the problem for prices not with the £ in front as mentioned above. It also is no use when prices are returned using Ajax.
- Go through every template file, every module class, every core class, every helper and every bit of JavaScript and leave the output as it is at present and duplicate whatever array key/object var is generated but suffix it with _formatted or similar and output that where necessary in the template. I'd also have to have a _calculated suffix too. So I'd have 10.00, 8.00, and £8.00 values for 10, 10*0.8 (vat) and £10*0.8 respectively.
- Go through all of the above mentioned files/sections/classes bar the templates and keep the single output but precalculated ready for templates so that I don't need to go through every template file.

The first option can't really work unfortunately for the reasons described above so Options 2, 3 and any you might suggest are on the cards I suppose. Unfortunately there's only 2 weeks scheduled in for the entire process (loads of other unmentioned but technically unrelated) functionality to go in) and the above options, given the size of the application will probably take me about a week.

Comment: You should not fix that in the output. Fix it before you output each number.

Comment: Indeed, I'd like to fix it before the output, I'm just looking for suggestions on how best to do so. Outputting it at template level is a terrible idea. Unfortunately the templates are plagued with calculations already so it's going to be a massive cleanup operation which is why I'd like to get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are those prices retrieved? You have no pricing abstraction, but you may have a DB abstraction. Maybe you can manipulate the prices on the query or right after it.

Comment: There is some database abstraction- are you suggesting that I catch all of the result objects and replace any fields which contain the word price with the output from some sort of pricing encapsulation/abstraction?

Comment: If you have a price field for each product - as I suppose you have -, you may perform numeric/formatting operations (add/remove VAT, currency changes etc) on the query itself, so the result is already manipulated according to your site wide setting (that will be known at query time). If the prices are inserted on text - so they're also just text - you'd better apply the replace function on those specific texts, not in the full $output. If the "£" presence in the template is uncertain, make sure the output generation includes it whenever needed and remove it from the templates.

Comment: I don't know what database system you're using, but take a look at these functions to have a better idea of what I'm talking about: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: If I perform it on all the queries at the query or result level this will cause problems on pre populated input fields etc though thinking about it. So an input field would be output as £8.00 but actually the value needs to be inserted with £10.00.

Comment: The system uses MySQL. The original author of the system uses select * almost everywhere so I'm going to have to rewrite almost every query if I do it that way. Plus there's a fair bit of logic which needs to be applied to a price to determine whether or not various settings mean that it's turned on/off and how much the vat percentage is depending on the user's locale/region etc which means I would probably have to modify the result object rather than pre selection?

Comment: If you need 2 values for the same field in a same page, you may (i) set the logic for the second value in your code or (ii) get 2 values from the database for the same field with an alias (price * 0.8 as price_without_vat, price etc). But only if the 2 values will be in the same page, otherwise you'd better control the query to only insert the operations needed for that page.

Comment: If you can't enforce that before the query, the second easier way is to manipulate the result set. The worst way is to manipulate the full page output. And the "best/right" way is to rebuild that app... ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4690/discussion-between-ben-swinburne-and-rodrigo-ferreira)

Comment: I made changes at the database abstraction layer which allowed me to solve part of this problem. Not all though. Fortunately I've palmed off going through each file to someone else. Many thanks for your help.